# Multiple Extension problem

Tags: controller-extension

I am working on Visualforce page which using standardController and has multiple extension.

```
<ape:page StandardController = 'CustomObject__c' extension = 'ClassA,ClassB'> 
       {!obj.field__c}
</apex:page>
```

---

```
    class classA {
       public CustomObject__c Obj{get;set;}
       public ClassA(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
            this.obj = (CustomObject__c)stdController.getRecord();
        }
    }
```

Now there is child window which class B as controller.

```
   <apex:page  Controller = 'ClassB' > 
        how to access obj here something like 
         {!obj.field__c}
   </apex:page>
```

---

```
   Class classB {
         i have to get obj here , assign some values and
         refersh the parent page with Standard Controller 
         to reflect the information 
     }
```

if I do below in Class B , It intiate a complete new record...

```
class classB public ClassB(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
            this.obj = (CustomObject__c)stdController.getRecord();
        }
```

Comment: Try passing in Class A as a controller, and making sure it has the `obj` as a public getter/setter.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're using two pages this isn't going to work, the controllers live in different execution contexts and so can't share data.

Instead you're going to have to load the record using the ID (passed as a page parameter) in controller B, modifiy it, and then use Javascript to refresh the parent page when the child window is closed.

Comment: Can't agree more on this ..Using JavaScript is best rescue here

Comment: Thanks Lacey and Mohith. I am going with a single extension approach now but facing some issue with re-rendering .. Please have a look below if you have some time. Thanks again  http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/78464/assign-value-through-param-in-child-window-but-not-reflecting-in-parent-window-e

Answer (score 1):

Extension controllers extend the properties and methods of either standard controller or custom controller. So if you have multiple extensions, they can access properties and methods of standard or custom controller it extends not the other extension's properties and methods.

So you cannot access Extension A's variables in Extension B and vice versa.

In your case, you are using class B as controller in second page. So it works as standalone controller and not an extension anymore. So you definitely cannot access either standard or custom controller properties in class B when using in second page.

Hope it helps.