# Assign value through param in child window but not reflecting in parent window even the extension is same

Tags: visualforce, rerender, apex-param

I have facing a weird issue with rendering . I have page with standard controller and extension

```
   <!-- Parent page -->
<apex:page StandardController = 'CustomObject__c' extension = 'xyz'> 
: code 
: code
<apex:actionfucntion name = "rendersection" rerender = "thepanel" action = "{!someactionmetiond}"
<apex:outputpnel id = 'thepanel' >
    {!Obj.field1__c}    
      {!obj.field2__c}
</apex:outputpnel>
```

```
class xyz {
           public CustomObject__c Obj{get;set;}
           public xyz (ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
                this.obj = (CustomObject__c)stdController.getRecord();
            }
           public PageReference processSelectedRow() {
    return null;
  } 
        }
```

Now,there is child window which has same controller and extension.

```
<!-- child Window_
<apex:page>
<script>
fucntion renderparent (){
  window.opener.rendersection();
  window.close;

}
</script>
:  code
:  code
<apex:column headerValue="Name" id="IdName">
     <apex:commandLink value="{!(lst.abc)}" action="{!processSelectedRow}" oncomplete="renderParent ();">
            <apex:param name="Name" value="{!(lst.abc)}" assignTo="{obj.field1__c}"/>
            <apex:param name="ExternalId" value="{!lst.ExternalId}" assignTo="{!obj.field2__c}"/> 
      </apex:commandLink>
  </apex:column>
:  code
:  code 
</apex:page>
```

Now the problem is , I have the assigned the new  values field1 and field2 through param and close the child window. Now , if I re-render the parent window , still it's not reflecting the new assigned value. why is this happening if constructor is the same.

Answer (score 0):

when you use window.opener.rendersection(); you will need to call a method (your ***someactionmetiond***) in the parent page, that re-query your Obj again or use stdController.reset()

---

**UPDATED**

As your record is not saved yet, you will need to pass the values by JS when you call your parent.

***Parent***

```
<apex:actionfucntion name = "rendersection" rerender = "thepanel" action = "{!someactionmetiond}">
    <apex:param name="Name" value="" assignTo="{obj.field1__c}"/>
    <apex:param name="ExternalId" value="" assignTo="{!obj.field2__c}"/> 
</apex:actionFunction >
```

***Child***

```
<script>
window.opener.rendersection('value1','value2');
```

Comment: Yeah. I am calling a function( someactionmethod ) and re-render the output panel  but still new values are not getting reflected. In addition , I also debug obj.field1_c and obj.field2__c in someactionmethod and it's debug the older values not the ones that are assigned through param.

Comment: What do you do in 'someactionmetiond' ?

Comment: Nothing.. 2 system.debug for field1__c and field2__c and return null.. earlier I thought it's not needed but put it to give a try

Comment: I think I said that in my answer. Can.you try to query your Obj before to debug?

Comment: Sorry.. do you mean to put [select field1__c,field__c from customObject__c]. Do I need to put the these field or all field.. My object has around 130 field...I thin k ,If  I reset it and other fields on the form also got reset and lose the values that end user filled so far.. please advide.. thanks a lot

Comment: That's right. Try to check out how to use reset method of standard controller

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention imp thing, record is not inserted yet. I am just receiving all the values in obj through getter/setter and will save the record once the form is saved....

Comment: Haha yeah that's quite important. That change everything.

Comment: Updated my answer, I hope that can help

Answer (score 0):

Write action function in parent page

```
<apex:actionfucntion name = "testaction" rerender = "testpanel" action = "{!testaction}">
    <apex:param name="param1" value="" assignTo="{param1}"/>

</apex:actionFunction >
```

form child window call

```
if jquery modal window then top.opener.testaction('value1');
For window.open
window.opener.testaction('value1');
```